# While doing some process how to block others in Jetpack Compose Android Studio?

Tags: android, kotlin, android-studio, mobile, android-jetpack-compose

In my application the main idea is first you select a target water liter then you click button and you fill your water level. Here after user reached the target I write You Reached Your Target and Blow up a confetti with LottieAnimation and after some delay I show an interstitial ad. But if I keep click on any button this click process is blocking and killing both confetti animation and ad to load. So I want to block all the processes until these finished. I used runBlocking to show ad it seems working fine but this time LottieAnimation is not working. I tried to put LottieAnimation inside the runBlocking but because of it is a composable it is not allowed. So how can I make my program to wait all the processes until these finished when the code met some condition? If this is not a correct way to do this process can you give me idea how to progress ? The code snippet below.

```
@SuppressLint("CoroutineCreationDuringComposition")
@Composable
fun MultiFloatingButton(
    multiFloatingState: MultiFloatingState,
    onMultiFabStateChange: (MultiFloatingState) -> Unit,
    items: List<MinFabItem>,
    waterTarget: Float
) {
    /* Other code part */
    /* Other code part */
    /* Other code part */
    /* Other code part */

    Box(contentAlignment = Alignment.Center,
        modifier = Modifier
            .fillMaxSize()) {
            if (progress >= MaterialTheme.dimens.progress) {
                if (!firstTime.getBoolean("firstTime", false)) {
                    clickEnabled = false
                    LottieAnimation(
                        composition = compositionConfetti,
                        speed = 0.75f,
                        iterations = 1)

                    LaunchedEffect(Unit) {
                        runBlocking {
                            delay(3000)
                            showInterstitialAd()
                            wavingScreenViewModel.mInterstitialAd?.show(context as Activity)
                        }
                    }

                    firstTime.edit().putBoolean("firstTime", true).apply()
                    clickEnabled = true
                }

                Text(
                    "HEDEFİNİZE ULAŞTINIZ!",
                    textAlign = TextAlign.Center,
                    fontSize = MaterialTheme.typography.bodyMedium.fontSize)

            } else {
                Text(
                    "%${(progress * 100 / MaterialTheme.dimens.progress).toInt().coerceAtMost(100)}",
                    textAlign = TextAlign.Center,
                    fontSize = MaterialTheme.typography.bodyMedium.fontSize)
            }
    }

}
```

Thanks in advance.